Cannot remove a tag because I did'nt change in the text
When I want to remove an unrelated tag from a question, I faced a problem; The system doesn't allow to save me because I didn't modify the text. Adding, however, a tag doesn't require to touch the text. There is nothing I want to change, all I want is remove the tag. 
There is a way to overcome this?

Sometimes you can get around these kind of restrictions by writing an extensive reason. Otherwise the way around this is to gain rep. As trusted user I can add / remove tags without even commenting or even appearing to have edited the question. I'm not sure how much rep. this takes though. Note that this is SE wide, it is not particular to crypto AFAIK.

I think 10000. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools Should I post the tag problem as comment for the question up to that time or leave it to the someonelse :)?

Depends on how important you think the change is. The reputation barrier is there for good reasons. It bars people from making too many changes. If you really think it is that important you can leave a comment for the authors / hi rep users. But please do not overdo edits because they may cost reviewers / mods more time than they are worth. That said, thank you for the $\TeX$ changes so far; those are time consuming and very worthwhile.

I'm trying to do my best. There are lots of stuff to learning and life is not enough as Marvin Minsky said on TED.

I think that the 2k editing privileges should suffice here. But the general idea is that "extremely minor edits are not worth the time of the usually two reviewers / could block more substantial edits / generate an edit spam on sites like stack overflow" and thus a minimum amount of change is enforced. But in my (admittedly somewhat dated) experience there are ways to game the system and make it see "changes" that actually aren't changes to get your minor changes through which are then usually approved if they still improve the post.
